Book about a man who is at the age where a lottery is taken of the elderly and he's chosen to be "put down", leaving a sad grandson
A man and his grandson are very close. When someone turns a certain age (70 or 80) they are put in a lottery of sorts and whoever is picked must be put to death, supposedly to control population. It wasn't a terribly long book.

Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please see our guide to asking story ID questions and [edit] your question with any additional details you remember (such as when you read this book).

Maybe The Lottery by Shirley Jackson, although it's not a man and his grandson, but a woman and her husband.
